# Python / Discord MEE6 - Use python to get a user's level on the MEE6 discord bot

Tags: python, discord

I am using python and is trying to get a user's level on the well known MEE6 bot's leveling system. I can't seem to find any way

I came across `mee6-py-api`, but it doesn't work for me. Seems like it's outdated, when I tried this code on my terminal

```py
from mee6_py_api import API
from asyncio import run

mee6API = API(your_guild_id) #i enter my guild id here
run(mee6API.levels.get_user_level(user_id)) #i enter my user id here, asyncio.run basically just allows me to run asynchronous functions without it being inside an asynchronous function.
```

it throws me the giant error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\junya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\junya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 608, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\junya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mee6_py_api\plugins\levels.py", line 55, in get_user_xp
    user_details = await self.get_user_details(user_id, guild_id, dont_use_cache, page_count_limit)
  File "C:\Users\junya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mee6_py_api\plugins\levels.py", line 42, in get_user_details
    leaderboard_pages = await self.get_all_leaderboard_pages(page_count_limit = page_count_limit, guild_id=guild_id)
  File "C:\Users\junya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mee6_py_api\plugins\levels.py", line 28, in get_all_leaderboard_pages
    leaderboard_page = await self.get_leaderboard_page(i, guild_id)
  File "C:\Users\junya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mee6_py_api\plugins\levels.py", line 20, in get_leaderboard_page
    result = await self.base_API.send_get_request_and_get_response(url, {'page': page})
  File "C:\Users\junya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mee6_py_api\api.py", line 87, in send_get_request_and_get_response
    check_http_response_for_errors(response, resp_status, resp_headers)
  File "C:\Users\junya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mee6_py_api\api.py", line 27, in check_http_response_for_errors
    raise get_http_exception_for_status(resp_status)("Received an unknown bad response from server. \n"
mee6_py_api.exceptions.UnauthorizedError: Received an unknown bad response from server.
response: {'error': {'message': "The server could not verify that you are authorized to access the URL requested. You either supplied the wrong credentials (e.g. a bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required."}, 'status_code': 401}
status: 401
header: <CIMultiDictProxy('Date': 'Fri, 15 Apr 2022 05:05:59 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '263', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://mee6.xyz', 'CF-Cache-Status': 'DYNAMIC', 'Expect-CT': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"', 'Report-To': '{"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\\/\\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\\/report\\/v3?s=ZPihimYGk2pKQiYl9q2W9T%2FlDlnyh5D6w1hQ4yov09TbRva%2FtAW7cCi%2FHgCV%2BR81mR1mD6S%2FD6LU1JMhWc1EAu%2B4nQ9lVyvPkRiLimUBfJsqh5PqOIxj9LKA"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}', 'NEL': '{"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}', 'Server': 'cloudflare', 'CF-RAY': '6fc2263959f5490c-SIN')>
```

It'll be very nice if there is somehow a fix to this, but I do not think so. What I'm looking for is one that just works properly.
Thanks,

Comment: I got a way but it's not really what I want, basically it's a discord bot that waits for the level up message from the MEE6 bot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not bother finding a fix for `mee6-py-api`, here is a better way to do it.

So turns out MEE6 has an api, and you can use something like the `requests` package to get the the json of a whole leaderboard of a guild by sending a `GET` request to `https://mee6.xyz/api/plugins/levels/leaderboard/guild_id_here`. So using the following code I can get the user level like this

```py
import requests

r = requests.get(f'https://mee6.xyz/api/plugins/levels/leaderboard/{your_guild_id}')
players_json = r.json()['players']
player_level = [i for i in players_json if i['id'] == str(user_id)][0]['level']
```

Hope it helped!