# How to create Discord Leveling System using MEE6

Tags: python, python-requests, discord, discord.py

I am working on a Discord bot for a server that has used MEE6's leveling system for many years. I would like to create a new leveling system with my bot while starting with the already stored data by MEE6. Could anyone give any guides as to how one can do this?

I headed over to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71880361/python-discord-mee6-use-python-to-get-a-users-level-on-the-mee6-discord-bot) and came up with this code to try and find MEE6's data for this server.

```py
import requests

r = requests.get(f'https://mee6.xyz/api/plugins/levels/leaderboard/{735338082647146496}')
players_json = r.json()['players']

user_id = 766571696491986965

player_level = [i for i in players_json if i['id'] == str(user_id)][0]['level']
print(player_level)
```

I get this error

```
'players'
  File "C:\Users\REDACTED\Downloads\leveling testing.py", line 4, in <module>
    players_json = r.json()['players']
                   ~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'players'
```

I wonder if MEE6's API has been discontinued or what the problem here is. If it has been discontinued, would there be any other way of finding the current levels data for the server?

***Edit:***

I've just tried heading over to the [MEE6 API link for the server](https://mee6.xyz/api/plugins/levels/leaderboard/735338082647146496) to try and see if I could access the data but I get this error

```
{"error":{"message":"The server could not verify that you are authorized to access the URL requested. You either supplied the wrong credentials (e.g. a bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required."},"status_code":401}
```

How could I get authorization to see this? I am admin on the server and can access the MEE6 dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

**Public / Private leaderboard**

Basically, I was unable to access the bot's leaderboard information as MEE6 restricts access to it.

To fix this, I headed over to https://mee6.xyz/en/dashboard/SERVER_ID/leaderboard then clicked the *Make my server's leaderboard public* checkbox. You must have access to  the server's dashboard to do this by having Administrator permissions